# Bundle dynamic imports into one chunk

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to bundle an ESM source file that uses dynamic imports like `e.push(import("./polyfills/dom.js"))`. It's a 3rd party script - so I can't change it.

By default, Webpack generates a chunk for each of these dynamic imports. But I'd rather like to have them bundled in an all-in-one file.

I've seen something like `webpackMode: "eager"` [exists](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) that claims to do exactly that, but I can't figure out how to configure my `webpack.config.js` accordingly (because it obviously doesn't work that way - all I see is a fancy comment syntax like `import(/* webpackMode: "lazy" */)` - which I cannot use because it's 3rd party code).

How do I use this properly?
Or is there another way to get all these dynamic imports into one single bundle?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./components/esm/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  }
};
```